# Database modeling in Laravel 5.4 with many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 entities.

1) Kpi

2) Subkpi

3) Department

The relationship between a KPI and a Subkpi is a One to Many (a kpi can have many subkpis) and between subkpi and department its many to many. Please see example below.

Kpi - Delivery

Subkpi - Code review

Department - Engineering, Operations

This combination of Kpi and Subkpi (Delivery/Code review) can belong to both (Engineering, Operations) departments. I have 3 master tables for these 3 entities having attributes like id, name and another pivot table to store the relationship of these 3, which has attributes id(primary key), kpi_id, subkpi_id, department_id. I have 2 questions now.

Q1 - Based on the relationship above, Is the database structure is correct? If not please help me to understand it?

Q2 - If the answer to Q1 is yes, then how can I get all the kpis/subkpis belongs to a department using Laravel's Eloquent ORM?

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: For me personally it is easier to understand what's going on if you post some code. Then we can also see what errors come up. Relationships are pretty easy to set up, just keep it simple and do it step by step.

Comment: You need pivot table to make many to many relation.

Comment: please share some code, this'll be easier to answer you then